# python call command line with Chinese Characters in windows fails

Tags: python, windows, gbk

Under python in windows, **in py script (test.py)**, os.system or subprocess.Popen calling the dos command fails, but succeeds under **command line (windows->cmd.exe)**, the script is as the following
additional info:

1. the dos (windows->cmd.exe) encoding is 'cp936', belonging to 'gbk'

2. I have decoded the test.py into utf-8 by notepad++

3 .decode('gbk'), .encode('gbk'), .decode('utf-8'), .enode('utf-8') have been tried

4. I do not know why

Error information:

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe E:/XtTradeClient/test.py
    File "E:/XtTradeClient/test.py", line 5 
    SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xba' in file E:/XtTradeClient/test.py on line 5,but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

    Process finished with exit code 1

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # encoding='utf-8'
    import os

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        info = '汉字'
        cmd = 'echo ' + info
        if 0 != os.system(cmd):
            raise Exception('failed to call 'echo in command')
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown error comes from a missing encoding comment.  It looks like you tried to add one, but the format is wrong, so it is not recognized.  Try:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Then the next problem might be the encoding the shell expects.  If your source code is saved as UTF-8 then the (byte) strings in it are UTF-8 encoded and handed that way to `os.system()`.  You may have to recode for the application that actually displays those bytes as characters.  That is: first decoding from UTF-8 to `unicode` and then from `unicode` to a `str` in the encoding of the terminal.  The explicit decoding can be avoided by using unicode literals, at least for (byte) strings with characters outside the ASCII range.

```
# encoding: utf-8
import os


def main():
    info = u'汉字'
    cmd = 'echo ' + info
    if not os.system(cmd.encode('gbk')):
        raise Exception('failed to call `echo` command')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding magic comment isn't correct. change it to `#-*- coding=utf-8 -*-`.

See [pep 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more info.

Comment: '# encoding=utf-8', '#coding=utf-8', '#-*- coding=utf-8 -*-' all work correctly, </br>More precisely, the first or second line must match the regular expression "coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)". "</br> --from the page pep0263